# Error: Error al ejecutar "javac -version", asegúrese de que tiene un JDK instalado

Tags: ionic

trato de correr este comando:
`$ ionic cordova build --release android`

que según la documentación de ionic me exporta el apk, pero me sale este error:

> Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK
>   installed. You can get it from:
>   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.
>
> [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema precisamente se indica en el mensaje

> Error al ejecutar "javac -version", asegúrese de tener un JDK
>   instalado. Puede obtenerlo en:
>   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.

No tienes instalado el [JDK que es un requerimiento necesario](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/platform-setup/windows-setup.html), debes instalarlo descargando desde url indicado.

Para saber si lo tienes instalado, una opción sería:

Ve a `Control Panel` > `Java` > Sección `Java` y `View`, te mostrara un listado el cual indica si tienes instalado el JDK

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se está debatiendo en Meta sobre las variantes de etiquetas de Ionic. ¿Te importaría darle una ojeada al debate como usuario importante en esa etiqueta? [Debate etiquetas Ionic](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4073/83)